# Javascript drag and drop file upload issue with webkitGetAsEntry

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

[Example JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xVzjx/10/)

The above fiddle is a stripped down version of my code just to highlight the issue (try dragging and dropping a file into the window). Basically, `webkitGetAsEntry().file()` isn't letting me write to anything outside its scope, however, if you drag a file and then manually do `console.log(fileList)` (however, jsfiddle blocks this) it works fine. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**upload.js**

```
function Upload() {
_this = this;
this.fileList = 'no file';

this.fire = function(droppedFiles) {
    for(i = 0; i< droppedFiles.length; i++) {
        this.buildFileSource(droppedFiles[i].webkitGetAsEntry());
    }
    //This returns the original string
    console.log(this.fileList);
}

this.buildFileSource = function(item, path) {
    if(item.isFile) {
        item.file(function(file) {
            _this.fileList = 'file';
            //This works as expected
            console.log(_this.fileList);
        } );
    }
};
}

//Event listeners for dragging  
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }, false);
        window.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }, false);
        window.addEventListener("dragleave", function(e) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }, false);

    window.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        upload = new Upload;
        upload.fire(e.dataTransfer.items);
        return false;
    }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log(_this.fileList);` in your `fire` function is being invoked before `fileList` is being modified in the `buildFileSource` method.  This is due to the fact that the `file` function on a `FileEntry` (your `item` variable) is an asynchronous one.  In effect, each call to `buildFileSource` is also asynchronous.  Seek out more details on the `Entry` interface and it's two children: `FileEntry` and `DirectoryEntry` on MDN.

Note that use of the `webkitGetAsEntry` method means that your code will only work on Chrome 21+ as this method is very specific to Chrome (due to the prefix) and the underlying concepts (`Entry` objects) belong to the Filesystem API, which only Chrome 21+ supports at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the help! With the asynchronicity in mind, I ended up just using `window.setTimeout` to poll a function that would return true once the files array had been populated and then continue execution. It's not an ideal solution, but it's working now. Also, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87969 seems to be saying that it's supposed to return synchronously, but maybe I'm not reading right.

Comment: I'm not aware of that bug, but it looks like it refers to webkitGetAsEntry.  The function I am referring to is the file function on your item/entry object, which is rightfully an asynchronous call.  And yes, your solution is not ideal.  I encourage you to embrace the asynchronous nature of filesystem API and refactor your code accordingly.

Comment: fwiw http://caniuse.com/fileapi says the FileApi was fully supported by chrome in version 13+

Comment: @Shanimal Yes, the File API was supported around this time.  I was talking about the Filesystem API, which was supported much later.

Comment: Actually FileSystemAPI was introduced with full support at the same time. http://caniuse.com/filesystem The features you are talking about specifically were added in version 21+... cheers